# Numerically integrate a function with an array as upper limit

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy, numerical-integration

I'm trying to integrate numerically a 1/H(z)dz, where the function H(z) is given by

```
def Hz_th(theta,z):
    aa,H0,omegam0=theta
    return np.sqrt(H0**2*(1 + z)**3*omegam0 + 3*H0**2*(1 + z)**3*aa*omegam0 + (1 + z)**3*np.sqrt((4*H0**4*(1 - omegam0))/(1 + z)**6 + (-(H0**2*omegam0) - 3*H0**2*aa*omegam0)**2))/np.sqrt(2)
```

Where z is an array

```
z = np.array([0.50349, 0.4952, 0.6782, 0.8672, 0.7992, 0.37129, 0.35568, 0.28391, 0.46691, 0.94791, 0.69391, 0.89791, 0.78991, 0.59091, 0.2102, 0.8592, 0.5592, 0.9972, 0.5834, 0.7972, 0.9142, 0.94921, 0.7342, 0.7662, 0.9842, 0.7012, 0.83716, 0.37016, 0.35816, 0.52216, 0.70116, 0.74526, 0.59116, 0.62039, 1.2024, 0.6104, 0.35819, 0.45138, 0.55239, 0.75039, 0.82238, 0.95039, 0.34039, 0.8104, 0.61191, 0.54891, 1.02991, 0.42291, 0.70191, 0.68591, 0.93291, 0.74991, 0.46891, 0.95991, 0.8412, 0.5632, 0.8292, 0.57921, 0.8652, 0.8592, 0.58621, 0.4892, 0.68921, 0.32416, 0.18516, 0.68116, 0.92116, 0.42816, 0.69916, 0.57516, 0.51116, 0.64116, 0.35116, 0.34916, 0.35486, 0.87116, 0.92516, 0.4194, 0.89038, 0.48038, 0.58038, 0.80538, 0.66438, 0.74538, 0.7364, 0.37039, 0.85039, 0.21938, 0.64739, 0.60038, 0.76039, 0.47039, 0.49791, 0.50791, 0.58791, 0.69992, 0.76191, 0.78891, 0.40591, 0.80892, 0.58392, 0.72091, 0.83791, 0.80691, 0.50016, 0.53316, 0.82116, 0.12516, 0.44316, 0.68339, 0.72639, 0.40439, 0.69038, 0.57639, 0.72039, 0.55091, 0.8489, 0.43591, 0.30191, 0.58119, 0.34621, 0.3312, 0.44939, 0.2916, 0.46109, 0.63291, 0.26891, 0.92591, 0.62591, 0.60891, 0.57891, 0.7202, 0.7672, 0.3682, 0.8492, 0.77721, 0.58421, 0.5892, 0.7692, 0.5142, 0.63821, 0.43521, 0.58421, 0.66259, 0.62116, 0.41616, 0.45117, 0.73316, 0.74116, 0.34916, 0.51416, 0.64339, 0.4704, 0.26338, 0.7424, 0.91039, 0.3374, 0.98339, 0.81338, 0.8174, 0.96038, 0.75639, 0.87891, 0.80991, 0.62791, 0.93491, 0.69791, 0.76791, 0.86491, 0.51491, 0.47091, 0.92891, 0.6312, 0.6162, 0.5652, 0.55819, 0.7362, 0.2622, 0.7622, 0.8592, 0.5592, 0.48016, 0.92116, 0.47516, 0.89216, 0.63116, 0.73516, 0.41816, 0.53516, 0.73416, 0.60916, 0.70116, 0.98216, 0.75816, 0.64339, 0.51539, 0.80538, 0.80039, 0.71538, 0.76639, 0.90139, 0.71839, 0.57938, 0.96038, 0.64839, 0.93639, 0.46138, 0.67039, 0.24639, 0.63892, 0.53591, 0.77391, 0.37091, 0.69992, 0.37391, 0.85391, 0.60392, 0.53491, 0.40091, 0.37191, 0.84091, 0.53216, 0.93116, 0.55316, 0.84116, 0.72739, 0.44238, 0.2824, 0.5194, 1.06039, 0.26838, 0.2504, 0.69892, 0.73091, 0.99891, 0.40991, 0.12694, 0.25609, 0.08848, 0.11797, 0.18322, 0.1407, 0.15186, 0.09401, 0.28662, 0.26349, 0.1431, 0.16035, 0.12303, 0.12608, 0.17315, 0.16431, 0.1599, 0.24448, 0.24835, 0.27544, 0.33051, 0.33103, 0.16059, 0.21887, 0.11991, 0.17839, 0.27923, 0.18581, 0.06641, 0.258, 0.2798, 0.26576, 0.185, 0.05715, 0.3264, 0.10886, 0.20323, 0.37986, 0.2116, 0.21353, 0.14409, 0.25249, 0.25672, 0.21885, 0.07883, 0.08282, 0.17028, 0.2367, 0.30569, 0.08254, 0.18891, 0.08141, 0.25655, 0.12622, 0.10264, 0.12455, 0.37046, 0.20215, 0.1799, 0.1618, 0.22669, 0.29683, 0.25029, 0.14882, 0.14729, 0.21513, 0.14478, 0.13243, 0.21975, 0.38492, 0.174, 0.17789, 0.29936, 0.11845, 0.17653, 0.24552, 0.19611, 0.24852, 0.30632, 0.24637, 0.13514, 0.21054, 0.2363, 0.17851, 0.22068, 0.31494, 0.18443, 0.26129, 0.18123, 0.38048, 0.18481, 0.20847, 0.17706, 0.31582, 0.24973, 0.20368, 0.12336, 0.20318, 0.15339, 0.33439, 0.1958, 0.24973, 0.15509, 0.15596, 0.15837, 0.30938, 0.24857, 0.18507, 0.18376, 0.18079, 0.17696, 0.17768, 0.0718, 0.13811, 0.1696, 0.24555, 0.14387, 0.25191, 0.03743, 0.27749, 0.28746, 0.19867, 0.15999, 0.21075, 0.23775, 0.15517, 0.09391, 0.15271, 0.25722, 0.21226, 0.2454, 0.13696, 0.32569, 0.10638, 0.40127, 0.18931, 0.19726, 0.12837, 0.12262, 0.12715, 0.21323, 0.21099, 0.26856, 0.20453, 0.2701, 0.24185, 0.29114, 0.35346, 0.28543, 0.21955, 0.17558, 0.23542, 0.15325, 0.21005, 0.29135, 0.31376, 0.13687, 0.29567, 0.30394, 0.20557, 0.1219, 0.17428, 0.24883, 0.24558, 0.13833, 0.24315, 0.24267, 0.31468, 0.27573, 0.30041, 0.21728, 0.20335, 0.19025, 0.29021, 0.22786, 0.31065, 0.13729, 0.08784, 0.08504, 0.19009, 0.09227, 0.12903, 0.26166, 0.26162, 0.19422, 0.14703, 0.21179, 0.17958, 0.19029, 0.3388, 0.11741, 0.2889, 0.26405, 0.24961, 0.22967, 0.08543, 0.27656, 0.36193, 0.30021, 0.11635, 0.15492, 0.25037, 0.25174, 0.12928, 0.30929, 0.29888, 0.27091, 0.29353, 0.18979, 0.12376, 0.31288, 0.30915, 0.20267, 0.21163, 0.1789, 0.30354, 0.21457, 0.32045, 0.21835, 0.07523, 0.2576, 0.18468, 0.11628, 0.06481, 0.10288, 0.04437, 0.16595, 0.16817, 0.17063, 0.12042, 0.13868, 0.2338, 0.24643, 0.22286, 0.17915, 0.19718, 0.22916, 0.26451, 0.10337, 0.21338, 0.15653, 0.2434, 0.23652, 0.20852, 0.25104, 0.22534, 0.28742, 0.32984, 0.24603, 0.11966, 0.32931, 0.21082, 0.20308, 0.28436, 0.18037, 0.2607, 0.14792, 0.32793, 0.24206, 0.22334, 0.1828, 0.15304, 0.13818, 0.20735, 0.20313, 0.19801, 0.22256, 0.2734, 0.18651, 0.15935, 0.21935, 0.17373, 0.24436, 0.13353, 0.28332, 0.17383, 0.19654, 0.36952, 0.20548, 0.17357, 0.12688, 0.28434, 0.19392, 0.10018, 0.37425, 0.11771, 0.19176, 0.23684, 0.15899, 0.07877, 0.13864, 0.23381, 0.15689, 0.08806, 0.13045, 0.18203, 0.25625, 0.21674, 0.14533, 0.13639, 0.20515, 0.36976, 0.1294, 0.26687, 0.27822, 0.17483, 0.11364, 0.11242, 0.15317, 0.19671, 0.18914, 0.17625, 0.21757, 0.18563, 0.16356, 0.25721, 0.12164, 0.16455, 0.19862, 0.26821, 0.40128, 0.14581, 0.05573, 0.22452, 0.28655, 0.18388, 0.10351, 0.33136, 0.21865, 0.26357, 0.16284, 0.10683, 0.16477, 0.1075, 0.12899, 0.05948, 0.04093, 0.01705, 0.01531, 0.01472, 0.02673, 0.01732, 0.04437, 0.01567, 0.02477, 0.038, 0.0299, 0.01012, 0.0258, 0.01038, 0.03791, 0.03507, 0.01268, 0.02525, 0.01908, 0.03489, 0.0295, 0.03416, 0.04067, 0.07515, 0.05581, 0.02529, 0.03501, 0.02846, 0.0328, 0.03378, 0.04597, 0.04341, 0.05684, 0.02024, 0.03191, 0.0415, 0.02639, 0.02651, 0.02689, 0.02349, 0.05067, 0.04093, 0.06877, 0.01754, 0.02557, 0.02189, 0.03155, 0.06845, 0.02249, 0.04949, 0.03161, 0.03434, 0.04486, 0.01531, 0.03048, 0.03837, 0.03682, 0.0221, 0.01402, 0.0589, 0.05895, 0.06888, 0.0204, 0.02894, 0.02384, 0.01451, 0.03292, 0.06455, 0.01663, 0.05359, 0.03163, 0.02751, 0.02559, 0.02401, 0.03713, 0.03408, 0.02454, 0.01697, 0.01629, 0.03184, 0.037, 0.02932, 0.0174, 0.03578, 0.02845, 0.05035, 0.04269, 0.03212, 0.02752, 0.03049, 0.01724, 0.07063, 0.05344, 0.02878, 0.03518, 0.03348, 0.04651, 0.06119, 0.04714, 0.0212, 0.04028, 0.03863, 0.03314, 0.02414, 0.02837, 0.01043, 0.02038, 0.0471, 0.03984, 0.0122, 0.01271, 0.01763, 0.02171, 0.01572, 0.01972, 0.01678, 0.01226, 0.05322, 0.03055, 0.03001, 0.01506, 0.0153, 0.04713, 0.03411, 0.0152, 0.01504, 0.02763, 0.03359, 0.01447, 0.02547, 0.01082, 0.01741, 0.02031, 0.04819, 0.02223, 0.02811, 0.05458, 0.05721, 0.02091, 0.01454, 0.0431, 0.03273, 0.03399, 0.01382, 0.05092, 0.01752, 0.02482, 0.0288, 0.01568, 0.02197, 0.03426, 0.01698, 0.02752, 0.03438, 0.01318, 0.01726, 0.01209, 0.05418, 0.0197, 0.01662, 0.02398, 0.03144, 0.01291, 0.03827, 0.01532, 0.02643, 0.0202, 0.0373, 0.02348, 0.01635, 0.02275, 0.2305, 0.3812, 0.2534, 0.1526, 0.4365, 0.1023, 0.3712, 0.4661, 0.1959, 0.3112, 0.0322, 0.1098, 0.2255, 0.2604, 0.2253, 0.4474, 0.4399, 0.3374, 0.5283, 0.5761, 0.3876, 0.36, 0.347, 0.4391, 0.3492, 0.4305, 0.5088, 0.2888, 0.1727, 0.318, 0.2752, 0.103, 0.2049, 0.2647, 0.2348, 0.2145, 0.4276, 0.4019, 0.3218, 0.4512, 0.1612, 0.3512, 0.2492, 0.0822, 0.1056, 0.3327, 0.1022, 0.2928, 0.1326, 0.2707, 0.1004, 0.3536, 0.4235, 0.3001, 0.1476, 0.2288, 0.1388, 0.1436, 0.0919, 0.1568, 0.2388, 0.1496, 0.5078, 0.2528, 0.2842, 0.2368, 0.3412, 0.2641, 0.349, 0.3212, 0.1352, 0.3065, 0.2335, 0.3006, 0.3676, 0.1692, 0.07976, 0.1806, 0.1806, 0.2307, 0.04582, 0.2212, 0.2006, 0.0755, 0.02627, 0.1912, 0.1777, 0.1852, 0.3491, 0.2712, 0.2921, 0.3704, 0.0963, 0.1808, 0.2748, 0.2454, 0.3618, 0.2318, 0.1466, 0.1592, 0.4198, 0.3192, 0.5196, 0.1506, 0.3026, 0.2106, 0.2396, 0.3316, 0.2006, 0.3606, 0.2426, 0.2212, 0.1206, 0.3412, 0.2504, 0.3804, 0.3106, 0.1994, 0.24, 0.5027, 0.3701, 0.27, 0.2631, 0.268, 0.308, 0.25, 0.2804, 0.3148, 0.3288, 0.3297, 0.2588, 0.2246, 0.2102, 0.3878, 0.3068, 0.3652, 0.2488, 0.2988, 0.1238, 0.3312, 0.3826, 0.2406, 0.1712, 0.2088, 0.2896, 0.2457, 0.1361, 0.1505, 0.1187, 0.2448, 0.3503, 0.6192, 0.2196, 0.0994, 0.4098, 0.5025, 0.3815, 0.2797, 0.2307, 0.4269, 0.5501, 0.3253, 0.3509, 0.3283, 0.4504, 0.06441, 0.06559, 0.3185, 0.1453, 0.1396, 0.4294, 0.2166, 0.3666, 0.3806, 0.4206, 0.1996, 0.5106, 0.4267, 0.3156, 0.5779, 0.4812, 0.3922, 0.1735, 0.3302, 0.2996, 0.2296, 0.2927, 0.2085, 0.2749, 0.3032, 0.359, 0.36, 0.349, 0.6304, 0.3207, 0.51, 0.3669, 0.1384, 0.1792, 0.1717, 0.2708, 0.3473, 0.4796, 0.3192, 0.5192, 0.3802, 0.3712, 0.1808, 0.2236, 0.1412, 0.3055, 0.4045, 0.2856, 0.3012, 0.2637, 0.5006, 0.3051, 0.3857, 0.1985, 0.0906, 0.4774, 0.3312, 0.4712, 0.3306, 0.2607, 0.07141, 0.1812, 0.3379, 0.1221, 0.2501, 0.1604, 0.2988, 0.3892, 0.2928, 0.3288, 0.3056, 0.2858, 0.4292, 0.1792, 0.1896, 0.2488, 0.4096, 0.2416, 0.3376, 0.0706, 0.3456, 0.3306, 0.05495, 0.4231, 0.1072, 0.2854, 0.3254, 0.3347, 0.2907, 0.4404, 0.2411, 0.4607, 0.1194, 0.545, 0.4114, 0.2688, 0.04976, 0.4118, 0.07369, 0.3188, 0.4198, 0.4208, 0.4392, 0.4804, 0.1998, 0.3018, 0.2902, 0.3092, 0.2956, 0.3386, 0.3782, 0.0896, 0.4507, 0.4604, 1.206, 1.33, 1.54, 1.55, 1.7, 1.8, 2.26, 1.914, 1.3, 1.34, 01.02, 0.735, 1.12, 1.23, 1.23, 0.854, 1.37, 0.9752, 0.97, 0.74, 1.39, 1.305, 0.935, 1.014, 1.315, 1.092])
```

Furtherly I need to use the integral for MCMC sampling of free parameters, contained in theta. I tried the following code to perform the numerical integration over an array

```
def MCMCf(theta,z):
    aa,H0,omegam0=theta
    return np.vectorize(lambda x: 1.0/Hz_th(theta,z))

def MCMCfint(theta,z):
    aa,H0,omegam0=theta
    return np.vectorize(integrate.quad(MCMCf(theta,z), 0, z))
```

But it does not work for me. Maybe someone could give an advice? I need to keep the functional form, because I could not provide the values of free parameters, they will be constrained with `emcee`.

There is a full traceback, when I'm trtying to plot the result with random true values as free parameters

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_17393/1708689059.py in <module>
      7     return np.vectorize(integrate.quad(MCMCf(aa,H0,omegam0,z), 0, z))
      8 z=z_values
----> 9 plt.plot(z,MCMCfint(aa_true,H0_true,omegam0_true,z))

/tmp/ipykernel_17393/1708689059.py in MCMCfint(aa, H0, omegam0, z)
      5 
      6 def MCMCfint(aa,H0,omegam0,z):
----> 7     return np.vectorize(integrate.quad(MCMCf(aa,H0,omegam0,z), 0, z))
      8 z=z_values
      9 plt.plot(z,MCMCfint(aa_true,H0_true,omegam0_true,z))

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py in quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit, points, weight, wvar, wopts, maxp1, limlst)
    346 
    347     # check the limits of integration: \int_a^b, expect a < b
--> 348     flip, a, b = b < a, min(a, b), max(a, b)
    349 
    350     if weight is None:

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: *"But it does not work for me."*  It will be easier for someone to help you if you explain what that means.  Did you get an error?  If so, include the complete error message (i.e. the complete traceback) in the question.  Did you get some other unexpected result?  If so, show what you got and explain what you expected.

Comment: There is an error occur `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

Comment: Don't use `vectorize` here.  If you need to iterate, do so explicitly.

Comment: @AlexSok, put the error message in the question (you should be able to edit the question), and include the *complete* traceback.  There is useful information in there.

Comment: Added the full traceback

Comment: The error occurs when `quad` tests the order of the lower and upper bounds., `a` and `b`.  That only works with the bounds are scalars.  You get this `ambiguity` error because `z` is an array (with more than one element).  `quad` CANNOT integrate between arrays.  Go back and read the docs if that isn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
import scipy.special as spec
from scipy.integrate
import quad
import numpy as np

array = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) # array[i] >= 0

for all i in [0, len(array) - 1].For example, array = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

constant = 3 # >= 0. For example, constant = 3

a = array

b = constant * a # multiply numpy array by a scalar(it is possible with numpy 

arrays(: ) c = b * a / constant

      e3 = spec.expn(3, c)

    

      print('Output:', e3) #

      return a ndarray with the value of the integral e3 en each point

specified in c(numpy array)

      # Output: [1.09691967e-01 2.76136095e-03 1.04786279e-05 5.96855753e-09 4.97790975e-13]

      # For evaluate the integral e3 from 0 to a[len(a) - 1]:

      result1 = e3[len(a) - 1] - e3[0] print('Output:', result1) # Output: -0.499999999950223

      # Other thing is the integral of e3 from 0 to a[len(a) - 1].You can use 
quad(
         return the value and an estimted error) # See https: 

      result2 = quad(lambda x: spec.expn(3, x), 0, c[len(a) - 1]) 

print('Output:', result2) # Output: (0.3333333333328521, 4.440892098500626e-16)
```

Comment: Ig u will get the idea by my code but if u don't understand then u can reply to me i will try another method.

Comment: I don't think that this method works for my case